# Comparing data that has been recorded on two devices

Tags: time-series, t-test, paired-data

I have two data loggers which are recording a physiological signal. Device A is a system that has been in place for many years, and records data ~once/minute. Device B is a prototype device which collects data ~40 times as often. The devices don't necessarily record synchronised data. Also, Device B does not record data on a regular time base.

I was intending to compare the two recordings using a t-test, but a colleague pointed out that  as the two devices are recording the same data they are not truly independent. However, as the data points were not collected simultaneously on both devices it's not possible to perform a paired t-test. Is there any other test that could be carried out to check the similarity of the two data sets?

EDIT: I'm not necessarily interested in the fact that it is a time series. Looking at the distribution of values recorded can be enough.

Edit2: The data is analysed in 2 different ways currently. A clinician will look at the trace itself, making conclusions simply by 'eyeballing' it. They will also look at a histogram of the values recorded.

Comment: "Is there any other test that could be carried out to check the similarity of the two data sets?" Is your intent simply to show that they give the same distribution of outputs (which you could test eg by comparing the CDFs)? This seems a bit odd since I would expect you to be more interested in checking their measurements agree when they're measuring the same thing (which in your case, if I understand your setup, means that their measurements at a given time should be close to agreement?).

Comment: In medical statistics a common way to compare measurements from two different devices is a [Bland-Altman plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot)

Comment: I know about Bland-Altman plots, but I don't think (could be wrong here) that it is applicable in this case as the data isn't collected at the same points in time.
The data is analysed in 2 different ways currently. A clinician will look at the trace itself, making conclusions simply by 'eyeballing' it. They will also look at a histogram of the values recorded.

Comment: That's correct about Bland-Altman and it now makes more sense why the distribution is all you care about from the histogram point of view (but you still need to do something different to check the traces agree, I'd suggest). Would I be correct to think you need to investigate whether the two devices produce similar output distributions *for each patient*? IE they should produce two similar histograms for Patient A, and two similar histograms for Patient B (possibly quite different to A), and so on?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. I need to confirm that the new device gives (effectively) the same result as the existing device.

Comment: Since not everybody reads the comments, you should probably try to edit some of these key points into your question - particularly the way the output gets used by the physician (as histogram and trace). For the histogram side of things, you're trying to test how well one whole bunch of empirical distributions match with their pairs, which is a harder task than just seeing if a single distribution matches its pair.

Comment: I have now edited the question, thanks for the advice.

Do I need to worry about 'pairing' the data in this instance though? (I realise you do not have all of the information here, so you may not be able to answer my question fully).

Comment: Should we read "Looking at the distribution of values recorded can be enough" as "looking at the distributions of values *on each patient*"?

Comment: Ah yes, I see your point. For now look at the single patient case, and if each patient recorded is statistically likely to have similar histograms that will be enough overall? In which case, which test would be appropriate to check the similarity of the two histograms for one patient?

Comment: You can compare one empirical distribution with another using eg [two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) but I wonder whether there is some kind of joint test you can do. Also this will only tell you if a pair of histograms are similar, not the pair of traces.

Comment: Thanks. Unless a better answer comes available, this will have to do.

Comment: I am concerned about your remark "Device B does not record data on a regular time base." If Device B is, say, turned on only after certain events occur, then there could be a strong sampling bias present, which would make your comparisons meaningless or misleading. Ideally you would extract data from both devices when they are simultaneously measuring the same patient.

Comment: @whuber yes, that would be ideal. Unfortunately the original device samples once per minute regardless (I have no way of controlling this) and I am collecting as much data as possible on the new device, which is roughly 41 times a minute, currently time stamped to the nearest second. Again, there is not much that I can do about this.

Comment: You're ok (1) so long as the devices are sampling the same things during the same time periods and (2) the times when both devices are doing that are representative of all times when either device might be used.

Comment: I tried using the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but because I had so many data points in the signal the power of the test made even the slightest difference between the signals significant. An alternative I have came up with is to split each signal into smaller sections, and to take the means of these sections. Then I will use these means to perform a paired t-test.

Answer (score -1):

A t-test is also not adequate because this is time series data.  You need to start with time series methods, which could be ARIMA or spectral analysis methods.

Comment: Will this matter if I am not particularly bothered about the time series aspect, and just interested in the distribution of values logged by each device?

Comment: Any autocorrelation will influence (heavily) the distribution of any test statistics you might compute, so is relevant, yes.